# JQuery - Click on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a design with a layover, like this:

```
.layover{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,1,0.7);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I use show this when a button is clicked, easy. It has another div in it, but I want to close this things when the `.layover` is clicked. But if I click the form over it, it still closes!

My javascript trying to close it:

```
$(".layover").on("click", function(){
    if(overlay_active){
        $(".layover").fadeOut();
        overlay_active = false;
    }
});
```

How can I make it that just if I click `.layover` that it closes, and not if I click on the `childs` of `.layover`?

Comment: The selected answer on that dupe is scary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".layover").on("click", function(e){
    if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;

    if(overlay_active){
        $(".layover").fadeOut();
        overlay_active = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I will accept as soon as I can.